# How to add Date's in Combobox Using Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hello Guys I want to make a Hotel Reservation system..
I have 3 combobox.. Lets say it is cboDays, cboMonth, cboYear.. When the form load I want to add items in cboDays, cboMonth, cboYears the days,month, and years. If I choose a month, cboDays will list all days depending if it is 31 days, 30 days, 29 days or 28 days. And also if I choose a leap year. Thank you guys in advance..

Comment: Using DateTime Picker would be easier ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I choose a month, `cboDays` will list all days

The built-in [DateTime.DaysInMonth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth(v=vs.110).aspx) function calculates the number of days for a given year and month:

```
Dim numberOfDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)
```

and it handles leap years too.

When the selected value of `cboYear` or `cboMonth` changes you need to update the values available in `cboDays`.